# Node.js: client doesn't die when TCP connection closes

Tags: node.js, tcpclient

I built a simple TCP server and a simple TCP client in Node.js

Now, when the client sends "exit" to the server, the connection is successfully closed. The server deletes the socket from its sockets list and sends "Bye bye!" to the client.

The connection on the client is closed as well but the app is still waiting for other inputs, so it doesn't die and I'm forced to type CTRL+C.

I tried adding `process.exit()` after connection closes but it doesn't work:

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
var net = require('net'),
    config = require(__dirname + '/config.json'),
    connection = net.createConnection(config.port, config.host);

connection.setEncoding('utf8');

connection.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected');
});

connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});

connection.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('» ' + data);
});

connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {

    if ((new String(data)).toLowerCase() === 'exit') {
        connection.end();
        process.exit();
    }
    else {
        connection.write(data);
    }

});

process.stdin.resume();
```

**SERVER CODE:**

```
var server = require('net').createServer(),
    config = require(__dirname + '/config.json'),
    sockets = [];

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding('UTF-8');

    socket.on('data', function (data) {

        console.log('Received data: ' + data);

        if (data.trim().toLowerCase() === 'exit') {
            socket.write("Bye bye!\n");
            socket.end();
        }
        else {
            sockets.forEach(function (client) {
                if (client && client != socket) {
                    client.write(data);
                }
            });
        }

    });

    socket.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Connection closed');
        sockets.splice(sockets.indexOf(socket), 1);

        console.info('Sockets connected: ' + sockets.length);
    });

    sockets.push(socket);
});

server.on('listening', function () {
    console.log('Server listening');
});

server.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Server is now closed');
});

server.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error:', err);
});

server.listen(config.port);
```

**EDIT:**

I added a client connection "on close" event handler. So, the string "Connection closed" is now printed by the server and by the client too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the `process.exit()` instruction only on the last event handler. So, in this case you have to put it inside the client connection "on close" event handler:

**CLIENT:**

```
connection.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    process.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for this: socket.unref().

From Node.js documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_unref):

> socket.unref()#
>
> Calling unref on a socket will allow the program to exit if this is the only active socket in the event system. If the socket is already unrefd calling unref again will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago when improving the tests suite for [node-cubrid](https://github.com/CUBRID/node-cubrid) module, I had encountered the same problem. After all tests have passed, nodeunit process didn't quit because node-cubrid was using `connection.end()` to close the client socket when timeout occurs, just like you did.

Then I [replaced](https://github.com/CUBRID/node-cubrid/commit/8cdd7c80c69d49bcc2f3671cfeb20f510fc2ceb0#L1R195) `connection.end()` with `connection.destroy()`, a cleaner way to ensure the socket is **really** closed without actually terminating the running process, which, I think, is a better solution than the above suggested `process.exit()`. So, in your client code context, I would do:

```
process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    if ((new String(data)).toLowerCase() === 'exit') {
       connection.destroy();
    }
    else {
       connection.write(data);
    }
});
```

According to [Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_destroy):

> **socket.destroy()**
>
> Ensures that no more I/O activity happens on this socket. Only necessary in case of errors (parse error or so).

Comment: I tried with `connection.destroy()` method, but in my application the result is the same. It closes the connection such as `connection.end()` does. The point is that after connection closes the process is still running, and only the `process.exit()` called after `connection.end()` or `connection.destroy()` gives me the desired behavior. Please, read my answer. You have to put the `process.exit()` only in the `connection.on('close')` event handler, so after the connection was closed (or destroyed). Try my code on command line.

Comment: `close` event isn't fired immediately when you call `end()`. It's called when the socket gets actually closed, eg. after `end()` the server says `bye` (which is +1 packet from the server), or right after `destroy()` which forces disconnection. Once the socket is closed, i.e. in `close` event handler, there is no point to `process.exit()` as that's the last thing the process will do anyway in your example.

Comment: no man, you have to call the `process.exit()` instruction, or the client doesn't die and you have to press the CTRL+C shortcut to be able to type on your shell. this is the QUESTION, and only the `process.exit()` instruction fix this behavior on the code that I posted for. If you've found another way that fix this specific behavior on my application please post this. the `connection.destroy()` didn't fix my hanging behavior. I've just tried.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that `if ((new String(data)).toLowerCase() === 'exit')` is succeeding because `data` most likely has a trailing newline (in your server, you `trim()` before doing the comparison, but not in the client).

If that's fixed, you've got a logic problem: when getting "exit" you close the connection without sending "exit" to the server, so the server code that looks for "exit" will never execute.

Comment: (new String(data)).toLowerCase() works perfectly, because the connection will closed successfully, infact the server send "Bye bye!" to the client and print "Connection closed\nSockets connected: 0"... so the client is disconnected, server is in listening for future connections but the client process (not connection) is still active

Answer (score 0):

Try with Event: 'close' in the server:
http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close